# Why is this question opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, opinion-based

[Should staying-at-home period waiting for specialized project better suits me be counted as working?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/104593/26826)

It asks for a yes or no answer, and the consensus is clear: no. So how can this be opinion-based? Why is it bad?

Comment: Lots of opinion-based questions have Yes/No answers. Q: *Are the New England Patriots the best NFL Football Team of this century?* And lots of opinion-based questions have a consensus answer. A: *Yes!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can this be opinion-based? Why is it bad?

**I don't think it is "bad". I think no post can ever be "bad" (the poster may have bad intentions though, as in the case of SPAM), so I wouldn't take it that way.** A post can be unclear or not useful, but not "bad".

However as you phrased it here it is clearly self-evident: *It is asking for a yes/no answer, and **that** is opinion-based.* Let us further analyze the questions you wrote on that closed post:

> Should this period be considered as working or not when we discuss my salary?

As we can see, some people may say *yes* or some may say *no* to this. That answer would depend on their opinion, thus opinion-based. This sort of questions are usually the ones *you* must decide, and also should be made considering your specific contract and work status.

> How should I approach this?

Again opinion-based. It is also quite broad and lacks a goal we can address (as there are many ways to approach things, but few of them that follow the goal you may have in mind).

In general, we can see that your post had some noticeable degree of opinon-based, and looking some comments over there we see that some folks also found it not really clear, hence another reason why it may have been closed. In fact your first question could also be company-specific, and depend on the way these things are usually handled in that company (or in your contract).

---

Another thing that didn't help you here is that **it seems you weren't engaged when you posted your question.** You posted it and had a 2 hour period where you did not respond to User feedback and clarification.

These "long" periods are well known to kill potentially good questions, as this community has a high degree of engagement from their users. For future instances **I suggest you stay engaged at least several minutes after posting your questions**, so you can clarify and edit your post and prevent it from being promptly closed.

Answer (score 2):

The basic issue with the original question is that too much depends on your financial situation.

If you start collecting salary without being on a project, the clock starts running. Once you reach some limit you will be let go, becasue you generated no income.

If you wait and don't collect salary, a different clock starts running. After too long they will forget that you have skills.

When you should take salary depends on how big your bank account is and how quickly it is getting depleted.

When you should grab the first project depends on the same thing: bank account and time left on the clock.

None of these are knowable by us, or generally the same for future readers.

Comment: But then the question should be closed as unclear, or they should ask me for more details, right?